# Having clause that filters out by max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-function

I'm trying to get the maximum date for an area_id from a 'review' table and return only those area_id's that have a max date_finished greater than one year (from today's date). The table structure is something like this

```
1) the 'review' table can have one or more reviews (multiple date_finished) for
each area_id
2) each region_id can have one or more area_ids
```

OBJECTIVE: Return the number of reviews per region_id with a date_finished greater than a year

Sample data:

```
region_id   area_id   date_finished
abc         area_3    '01-01-2010 12:00:00 AM'
abc         area_3    '06-01-2009 12:00:00 AM'
abc         area_3    '02-01-2008 12:00:00 AM'
```

The expected result above should be return region abc and count should be 1 (because the max date_finished is january 1, 2010 and that is greater than a year from today's date (2013)

The sql I have is below. For some reason it returns all of the dates I have described above. Instead of returning the max date it returns 3 dates. I'm using SQL Server 2008. Thanks!

```
select count(*) 
from review group by area_id 
having datediff(day,max(date_finished), getdate()) > 365
```

Comment: is the data type of your column `date_finished` varchar (*string*) or date?

Comment: So, the only valid values for your `COUNT` should be `1` if the max date is over a year ago, and `0` otherwise?

Comment: It's date....i guess i need to write out the whole date

Comment: @Lamak -  just not show up at all in the results...that would be ideal case

Comment: So, what you really want is to return rows where the max finished date per region was longer than one year ago?, no count?

Comment: @Lamak - What I want to do is return a count of the different area_id's (per region_id) that have a max date_finished greater than a year ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get what you want through two levels of aggregation, first by region and area, the second by region:

```
select r.region_id, count(*) as NumAreas, SUM(cnt) as NumReviews
from (select r.region_id, r.area_id, count(*) as cnt,
             MAX(date_finished)as maxDF
      from review r
      group by r.region_id, r.area_id
     )  r
where DATEDIFF(day, maxDF, getdate()) > 365
group by r.region_id
```

Comment: YES!!! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Specifically the NumAreas. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use WHERE clause instead of HAVING

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't making a lot of sense to me.
You want a count of the maximum date that meets a certain criteria.
That logic resolves to a boolean.
Because a date that meets your criteria either exists or it doesn't.

```
;WITH CTE (region_id,   area_id,   date_finished) AS
( 
    SELECT 'abc',         'area_3',    CAST('2010-1-1' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abc',         'area_3',    '2009-3-1'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'abc',         'area_3',    '2008-6-1'
)
SELECT   region_id
        ,HasQualifyingVal   =  CASE  WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM CTE
WHERE date_finished < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, date_finished)
GROUP BY region_id
```